# Unable to click link using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click on the link shown below:

```
<a class="user" href="/Kevin-Rose" action_mousedown="UserLinkClickthrough" id="__w2_L73qRYl_link" 
target="_blank">
         <span class="matched_term">Kevin Rose</span>
</a>
```

I tried using following code:

```
 user = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='user'][1]")
 user.click()
```

I got following error:

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the link is visible? Can you provide us with a link to the website under test?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/search?q=Kevin+rose

Comment: Do you want to click any particular link ? Can you post screenshot by highlighting required link to click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are finding the element while it is not yet there. [`Wait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for it.

Here's the complete code, from logging in, search to following the first `Kevin Rose` link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


URL = "http://www.quora.com"
EMAIL = 'your email here'
PASSWORD = 'your password here'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # can be webdriver.Firefox() in your case
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# login
form = driver.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
username = form.find_element_by_name('email')
username.send_keys(EMAIL)

password = form.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

login_button = form.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit" and @value="Login"]')
login_button.click()

# search
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@name='search_form']//input[@name='search_input']")))
search.send_keys('Kevin Rose')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# follow the link
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Kevin Rose")))
link.click()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly.Thanks a lot. I was using python shell and executing the code line by line,then why wait is required?

Comment: @Siddhesh since quora loads the page asynchronously, not all the elements are there after the initial data comes. Waits is a pretty neat technique comparing to lots of `time.sleep()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below locators

```
Xpath : "//span[text()='Kevin Rose']"

cssSelector : "a[href*='Kevin-Rose'] > span"
```

**Edit-I**

Here is the Xpath to click on Profile name Kevin Rose

```
"//div[contains(.,'Profile:') and contains(@class,'photo')]/span/a//span[text()='Kevin Rose']"
```

Comment: It didn't give any error but i am on the same page. There are multiple instances of "Kevin Rose" may be that is the reason. My pointer was in the search box when i selected the element. I will try with different indexes and check if it works, but thats again a tedious task.

Comment: Do you want to click any particular link ? Can you post screenshot by highlighting required link to click?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added xpath. Try with that and let me know.